# React В render данные из componentDidMount undefined

Tags: reactjs

Не могу манипулировать с данными в render, что странно.

Код:

```
class Pagination extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log(this.props);
    const { id, count } = this.props;

    let pages;
    if (count != 0) {
      pages = Math.ceil(count / 12);
    }
  }

  render () {
    console.log(this.pages); // undefined, в componentDidMount все нормально

    ...
```

Что я упускаю?

Comment: ну так в `componentDidMount` изменяется `let pages;` а не `this.pages`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так получается потому что с начало работает метод `render` (в котором `this.pages` еще `undefined` ) потом `componentDidMount`.Поэтому возвращает `undefined` вот цикл смотрите в раздел **Mounting**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И почему вы используете объявление переменной  `pages` внутри `componentDidMount` у вас же есть `state`.Старайтесь по максимуму избежать такого кода.

Comment: Перенес код `const { id, count } = this.props;` в `componentWillMount` все равно `undefined` в `render`.

Comment: @TimurMusharapov componentWillMount уже deprecated  вот вам рабочий вариант https://codesandbox.io/s/naughty-feather-ylktm .Но так делать не советую лучше всего объявляйте  в самом render там же используйте

Answer (score 1):

У вас pages никуда не сохраняется после выхода из componentDidMount. Нужно, let pages сохранить в локальный стейт, потом его уже доставать в рендере. Вот пример на хуках:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Component count={154}/>
    </div>
  );
}

function Component(props) {
  const [pages, setPages] = useState(0);
  useEffect(() => {
    const {count} = props;
    if (count !== 0) {
      setPages(Math.ceil(count / 12));
    }
  }, [props]);
  return (<>{pages}</>)
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```